# Python - Counting the number of files and folders in a directory

Tags: python-2.7

I've got a python script that deletes an entire directory and its subfolders, and I'd like to print out the number of files and folders removed. Currently, I have found some code from a different question posed 2010, but the answer I receive back is 16... If I right-click on the the folder it states that theres 152 files, 72 folders...

The code I currently have for checking the directory;

```
import os, getpass

user = getpass.getuser()
copyof = 'Copy of ' + user
directory = "C:/Documents and Settings/" + user
print len([item for item in os.listdir(directory)])
```

How can I extend this to show the same number of files and folders that there actually are?

Comment: this python script doesn't count files which are contained in subfolders. Thus you see discrepancy in numbers

Answer (score 3):

To perform recursive search you may use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk).

> os.walk(top, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=False)
>
> Generate the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up. For each directory in the tree rooted at
>   directory top (including top itself), it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath,
>   dirnames, filenames).

Sample usage:

```
import os
dir_count = 0
file_count = 0
for _, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_to_list_recursively):
    dir_count += len(dirs)
    file_count += len(files)
```

Comment: Using this script, and adding in the directory, I get;
    valueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: Ugh, my bad, quoted good function from documentation, used bad in example.

Comment: I've got a bit of it working... I can now successfully count the number of files in a directory and its subdirectories, but how can I expand this to take into account folders?

http://pastebin.com/b70vWUqB

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by using the following code by octoback (copied directly);

```
import os
cpt = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk("G:\CS\PYTHONPROJECTS")])
```